# Radius of Convergence of the Power Series Solution to a Second Order Linear Homogeneous ODE

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I was studying the proof of the following theorem

> **Theorem**. Let $x_0$ be a real number and suppose that the coefficients $a(x)$, $b(x)$ in
>   $$L[y](x)=y^{''}(x)+a(x)y^{'}(x)+b(x)y(x)\tag{1}$$
>   have convergent power series expansions in powers of $x-x_0$ in some interval as follows
>   $$a(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(x-x_0)^n, \quad b(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_n(x-x_0)^n, \quad |x-x_0| \lt r_0, \quad r_0 \gt 0\tag{2}$$
>   Then there exists a nontrivial solution $\phi$ of the problem
>   $$L[y](x)=0 \tag{3}$$
>   with a power series expansion
>   $$\phi(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_n(x-x_0)^n\tag{4}$$
>   convergent for $|x-x_0|<\rho$ where $\rho \ge r_0$.

**Proof Outline**

The proof is straight forward. It considers the power series expansions of the coefficients in $(2)$ which are convergent for $|x-x_0| \lt r_0,\,r_0 \gt 0$. Then it puts the series solution $(4)$ into the ODE mentioned in $(3)$ and obtains a recurrence relation for the $c_i$*s* such that the ODE is satisfied. Then it proves that the series solution $(4)$ whose coefficients obey the aforementioned recurrence relation will converge in the interval $|x-x_0| \lt r_0$.

The following links show the original proof if you want to check it out.

[Proof, Page 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GicIw.png)
[Proof, Page 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VolCP.png)
[Proof, Page 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLkXC.png)

---

**Question**

According to the proof, it can be concluded that the solution will converge for $\rho=r_0$.

The proof does not mention anything about the last sentence of the theorem that $\rho \ge r_0$ which is saying that $r_0$ is lower bound for radius of convergence of the solution.

I just cannot understand that how the radius of convergence of the solution can be $\rho \gt r_0$. I think having $\rho>r_0$ is meaningless as the coefficients of ODE can just be replaced by their power series only in $|x-x_0|<r_0$.

Can someone shed some light on this?

Comment: There seems to be some parts missing. It is a linear, homogeneous ODE and no initial value given. So obviously $y(x)\equiv 0$ is a solution. This solution is btw. converging on $\mathbb{R}$. So you could skip the whole given proof. And this seems also to answer your question. In the worst case, the radius of convergence might be $r_{0}$ but it can be larger or even be infinity.

Comment: @Alex: Thanks for attention. No parts is missing. :) You don't need initial values to prove the things mentioned in the theorem. You are forcing me to say what if we exclude the trivial solution $y=0$!? :)

Comment: Yeah, of course the interesting part is the non-trivial solution. I just wanted to make the point that if this is really the Theorem without excluding the trivial solution, there was nothing to prove :-)! I will think about what you asked...

Comment: Ok, if I get the idea right $c_{i}$ is a function of $(a_{n})$ and $(b_{n})$. So given the $a_{n}$ could one not just choose the $b_{n}$ such that the $\phi(x)$ is converging in a larger radius of convergence buy just making many of the $c_{i}$ zero? This would be recurrence 9.9 in the files you gave.

Comment: And again to be even more precise: The author does not speak of the convergence radius of the involved functions but just claims that both $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ are convergent AT least in that given interval. So both series could converge also in $\mathbb{R}$ and of course then the power series of the solution would also converge on $\mathbb{R}$. So it is just not very sharp.

Comment: @Alex: In fact, I think that the author means that $r_0$ is the minimum of radii of convergence of the power series of $a(x)$ and $b(x)$. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The followings are other examples that show there may exist **nontrivial** solutions which are analytic at $x=0$ with their radius of convergence being greater than that of coefficients of the ODE.

$$\begin{array}{rcll}
y''+ \dfrac{x}{1-x} y'-\dfrac{1}{1-x} y=0, & & y=x \\
y''- 2\dfrac{x}{1-x^2} y'+ \dfrac{n(n+1)}{1-x^2} y=0, & & y=P_n(x), & \text{Legendre Differential Equation}
\end{array}$$

There is also a nice example in the answer by @Alex. However, in all of the examples, the radius of convergence of the solution we are interested in is $\infty$. I couldn't find some example which the radius of convergence of solution is greater than that of coefficients but it is not $\infty$.

I think any arguments about $ρ>r_0$, in such a proof, is meaningless as the coefficients of ODE can just be replaced by their power series only in $|x−x_0|<r_0$. But sometimes, **luckily**, the solution we obtained formally by this method satisfies the ODE while we **have not** replaced the coefficients by their power series. In this case, what just matters is the radius of convergence of the solution itself.

Answer (score 1):

I think, I have found an example for you. Suppose $a(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^{2}}$ and $b(x)=-1-\frac{1}{1+x^{2}}$. Then, obviously, both power series have radius of convergence $1$ with $x_{0}=0$ but as solution you can find
\begin{equation}
y(x)=\exp(x).
\end{equation}
So there is at least one solution which has greater radius of convergence, (even infinity) and for that both $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ can still have the same radius of convergence.

Comment: (+1) Really nice example. So, what is the point that we are missing in the analysis? I mean this would show up in the proof of theorem some where! We may spot the point if you take the whole computations with this example.

Comment: Are you there Alex? :)

Comment: Now I am. Yeah, I would expect that if you compute the $c_{i}$ that you get they will decrease sufficiently fast, such that you get a larger existence interval. Maybe you can use the formula 9.9 and assume that $c_{0}=c_{1}=1$ (to get exactly the exponential function) and then you would just have to clarify that the recurrence indeed give $c_{k}=\tfrac{1}{k!}$. If you cannot make it, let me know, I will try it then.

Comment: I thought about it, I think having $\rho>r_0$ is meaningless as the coefficients of ODE can just be replaced by their power series only in $|x-x_0|<r_0$. But sometimes, luckily, the solution we obtained formally satisfies the ODE while we have not replaced the coefficients by their power series.

Comment: Isn't it more that in principle the solution does not have to be analytic to satisfy the differential equation. So for the example I gave above we have still functions with are $C^{\infty}$ on $\mathbb{R}$ but not analytical. So there might be a solution which satisfies the ODE. It might also be reasonable to reconsider that the function I gave are not analytical on the whole $\mathbb{R}$ but except $|x|=1$ they can locally been developed into a power series. So clustering the whole $\mathbb{R}$ with different discs of convergence could do the trick, if the solution remains bounded....

Comment: Hi again. :) What you gave as the example has analytic coefficients every where! :) What you said will be true if we have $1-x^2$ instead of $1+x^2$ in denominators. Please complete your answer so that I can accept it. :)

Comment: No, there is not power series of $\frac{1}{1+x^{2}}$ over the whole $\mathbb{R}$. You have to cluster. This is due to the fact that   $\frac{1}{1+x^{2}}$ has roots at $\pm i$ , such that the radius of convergence will never go "over" 1....

Comment: Ooops! you are mixing two things! A function is called analytic at a point if it has a convergent power series with nonzero radius of convergence. It is not necessary for the radius of convergence to be $\infty$ to cover the whole $\mathbb{R}$!

Comment: That is what I meant with clustering...

Comment: So do you accept that the coefficients in your example are analytical on the whole $\mathbb{R}$!? :)